# Good alternative to .net DateTimePicker?

Tags: .net, custom-controls, datetimepicker

I can't really explain why exactly, but I really hate the .net DateTimePicker control built into C#.net and VB.net.  Is anyone aware of a good alternative to either of these controls which is freely available?  I'm sure I'm not the only one who doesn't like the control.

The date picker in Google Calendar is one which I really like, so I'd love something like that which I can use in a .net app.

Comment: Talking about feelings.. I really hate the asp.net CalendarExtender..

Answer (score -2):

Check out [jQuery Date Picker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) It might take some configuring and styling but it looks like you could get close to what Google offers with this.